# No previous prototype for function

Tags: ios, function, prototype, core-audio

I'm adding [this tone generation code](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) to an existing project of mine but I'm doing something wrong and can't figure out what the problem is. The code works fine in the stand alone project.

```
OSStatus RenderTone(
    void *inRefCon, 
    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
    const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
    UInt32 inBusNumber, 
    UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
    AudioBufferList *ioData)

{
    // Fixed amplitude is good enough for our purposes
    const double amplitude = 0.25;

    // Get the tone parameters out of the view controller
    ToneGeneratorViewController *viewController =
        (ToneGeneratorViewController *)inRefCon;
    double theta = viewController->theta;
    double theta_increment =
        2.0 * M_PI * viewController->frequency / viewController->sampleRate;

    // This is a mono tone generator so we only need the first buffer
    const int channel = 0;
    Float32 *buffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;

    // Generate the samples
    for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) 
    {
        buffer[frame] = sin(theta) * amplitude;

        theta += theta_increment;
        if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI)
        {
            theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;
        }
    }

    // Store the updated theta back in the view controller
    viewController->theta = theta;

    return noErr;
}
```

In the controller where I'm adding the code I only have warnings saying `No previous prototype for function 'RenderTone'` (repeatedly)

I'm also getting a few errors but these aren't located in the source files I've written myself:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add AudioToolbox.framework to your project.

Comment: This remove the errors but not the warnings. Any idea what could fix those?

Comment: @Sled, Here is your ToneGenerator sample, No error, No warning...Enjoy!  http://is.gd/en50Zt